# How to understand AnimationRate->r, where r is variable?

Tags: list-manipulation, animation

Consider such an example

```
Clear[list];
list = {};
f[t_]:=0.1 + 0.5 t;
Animate[AppendTo[list, t], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}, AnimationRate -> f[t], 
  AnimationRepetitions -> 1, DisplayAllSteps -> True, TrackedSymbols :> {t}]

ListPlot[list]
```

> {0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.11,0.12,0.14,0.16,0.18,0.2,0.22,0.25,0.28,0.31,0.35,0.39,0.44,0.49,0.55,0.62,0.7,0.79,0.89,1.}

> [image]

It looks like the speed of the slider is getting faster, I wonder how the list is generated. Is there an iteration that produces a list equivalent to this list?

Comment: You specified: `AnimationRate -> f[t]`. As f[t] is getting larger, the animation will speed up.

Comment: The `list` may be different each time the code is run (and probably will be). -- "I wonder how the list is generated": A value of `t` is appended to the `list` every time the list is updated by `Animate`.  Since `AppendTo` is used, eventually the animation will slow down; however, the amount `t` is changed each update increases, as shown in the plot.